# Gradle ignores excluded transitive dependency from maven pom

Tags: maven, gradle

We have a library that wraps the [dropwizard lifecycle library](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/dropwizard/dropwizard-lifecycle/3.0.3/dropwizard-lifecycle-3.0.3.pom). In the previously linked pom you can see that it specifies exlusions on *org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-servlet-api*.  Our library respects that inclusion, and does not pull in that excluded library.

Our gradle application that has our wrapping library as a dependency however, does pull in the jetty-servlet-api.

We worked around this by excluding the jetty-servlet-api again in Gradle, but this doesn't seem right. How do we make sure gradle respects the exclusions from the POM file? Github issues like this one: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22370 make me think that this scenario shouldn't be coming up, but it is.